# Adding Buttons to notification

Tags: java, android, button, android-notifications

I have a notification that shows up fine, but when I add the last line to add a button, I just never know what to use as intent, could you demonstrate on this code;

```
  NotificationCompat.Builder  mBuilder = 
  new NotificationCompat.Builder(this); 

  mBuilder.setContentTitle("Updated Message");
  mBuilder.setContentText("You've got updated message.");
  mBuilder.setTicker("Updated Message Alert!");
  mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.woman);
  mBuilder.addAction(
```

And explain what should go into addAction(), Basicly I want the user to click on a button and open the browser. I don't want to start a new activity or anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the documentation

> A notification can provide multiple actions. You should always define
>   the action that's triggered when the user clicks the notification;
>   usually this action opens an Activity in your application. You can
>   also add buttons to the notification that perform additional actions
>   such as snoozing an alarm or responding immediately to a text message;
>   this feature is available as of Android 4.1. If you use additional
>   action buttons, **you must** also make their functionality available in an
>   Activity in your app; see the section Handling compatibility for more
>   details.

Comment: I Was hoping for a way around it, but I guess it's not possible, although it would be even nicer to be able to put a texField to get string from the user, maybe on Android 4.5 Kinder? Staying tuned...